# Update the Excel list, with data from database

Tags: sql, excel, database, pivot, powerquery

So, I have this Excel list with data, that I get from my database: 
Excel:

```
--------------------
|IDPerson|Name     |
--------------------
|    1    | Philip |
--------------------
```

Now I have new data that also should be updated into my excel list 
Sql Database:

```
--------------------
|IDPerson|Name     |
--------------------
|   1     | Philip |
--------------------
|   2     | Dave   |
--------------------
|   3     | Ben    |
--------------------
```

What I want on Excel, after I press something like a Update-Button:

```
--------------------
|IDPerson|Name     |
--------------------
|   1     | Philip |
--------------------
|   2     | Dave   |
--------------------
|   3     | Ben    |
--------------------
```

Do some of you have a recommendation on what to use, I looked something named "Power-Query" up:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/tutorial-import-data-into-excel-and-create-a-data-model-4b4e5ab4-60ee-465e-8195-09ebba060bf0

Comment: This is not on-topic for SO. For questions on tools and libraries, I suggest https://superuser.com/.

Comment: Create a table in Excel that is linked to your SQL database. When you click refresh it will update the table with new data from the SQL server.

Comment: That link you posted is not about Power Query but about legacy data connectors in Excel. They still work I guess, but Power Query is usually easier to use and is standard in Excel 2016 and later. It is also free as an add-in for Excel 2013. What version of Excel are you using?